# How to calculate autocorrelation coefficient at lag 2?

Tags: econometrics

$\text{AR}\left(1\right)$ Model:

$y_t = 0.6 y_t-1 + u_t$

Where $u_t$ is a white noise process with $Var\left(u_t\right) = 1$.

So far I have calculated $Var\left(y_t\right) = 1.5625$ but am unsure how to calculate the covariance?